# Why am I feeling too weak that can’t stand up after seeing new syllabus before two days of exam?

Tags: neurology, nervous-system, shake-tremble-fidget, central-nervous-system

My heart rate increasing, hand is shaking, feeling too weak that can’t stand up

Why is this happening to me??

Comment: Although anxiety is a possible cause (as the person who answered stated), and heart problems and strokes are rare in younger people - they still do happen and can be triggered by anxiety. Yyour symptoms should be evaluated by a medical professional.  Rules of HealthSE do not permit personal health advice questions and should not be answered as such.  It is dangerous to diagnose you online.  I recommend being seen by a primary care physician for a same-day visit, or go to an urgent care or ER.  If you are weak, don't drive yourself, and consider calling 911.

Answer (score 1):

It is safest to be evaluated by a medical professional. The rules of HealthSE don't permit personal health advice questions. If you are still experiencing symptoms - as above, get seen urgently or phone for help.

Comment: Although this is excellent information on panic attacks, please review the help files for Health SE. Personal health advice and "diagnose me" questions are not allowed. Also, references should be included in answers. 
 Great info though, appreciate the CBT reference.